# CIM_VolumeView is not a valid className for EMC SMI-S provider 8.1 version

Tags: storage, emc, wbem

I was using CIM_VolumeView className to get all information about LUNs and related StoragPools on my EMC VMAX SMI-S provider 4.6.x version year ago.

I am getting error message: `CIM_VolumeView is not a valid className for namespace root/emc` when I am trying to use this className against SMI-S provider 8.1x version.

Can someone provide me with correct className to get the same information on EMC VMAX SMI-S provider 8.1.x version.